# Laravel : Trying to get property 'street' of non-object

Tags: laravel

I read  other questions but I don't find my answer.
 my problem is:

> Trying to get property 'street' of non-object (View:
>   /Users/acny/Desktop/Bongah/resources/views/banners/show.blade.php)

This is `show.blade.php` :

```
<div class="col-md-4">
        <h1>{{ $banner->street }}</h1>
        <h2>{{ $banner->price }}</h2>
        <div class="description">{{ $banner->description }}</div>
    </div>
```

and Controller :

```
public function show($zip, $street)
    {
        $banner = Banner::locatedAt($zip, $street);
        return view('banners.show', compact('banner'));
    }
```

Thank for your help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Probably, no banner was found so your `$banner` variable is `null`. So it basically tries to get the `$banner->street` property of a non-object (in this case, `null`).

It's like doing `null->street` which clearly doesn't make any sense written this way.

Comment: but I defined banner : $banner = Banner::locatedAt($zip, $street);

Comment: yes but did you actually test what `$banner` is equal to ? A variable can be defined without being an object. I said it was probably equals to `null` since it is often the case, but the same error could appear if `$banner` was equal to a `float`, a `boolean` or anything else that is not an object. Just after `$banner = Banner::locatedAt($zip, $street);`, write a `dd($banner)`. It will show you what `$banner` really is.

Comment: Yes that is it. dd($banner) = null  because database deleted. Thank you very much